# MVP pattern+async+update UI

Tags: c#, асинхронность, mvp

Есть некая задача, по которой надо обработать данные в массиве из большого количества элементов. Данные, это кадастровые номера, по которым надо запросить, с некоторого сайта, данные.

Есть так же форма, на которой лежит ProgressBar и два label's, которые показывают количество обработанных номеров и сколько номеров всего.

Дальше всё примерно так:

```
private async void CnfBtnOkClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    // cnumbers - string[] с номерами
    await ParseNumbersAsync?.Invoke(cnumbers, threadCount).ConfigureAwait(true);
    //...
}
```

Где-то в презентере

```
private async Task ParseNumbersAsync(string[] cnumbers, int threadcount)
{
    // Делим массив на несколько массивов по количеству потоков
    string[][] datas = cnumbers.Split(threadcount);
    Task[] tsk = new Task[threadcount];
    for(int i = 0; i < threadcount; i++)
    {
        tsk[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(datas[i]), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tsk).ConfigureAwait(true);
}
```

Внутри DoWork цикл по номерам, а внутри цикла конструкция

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => UpdateUI, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _ts);
```

Внутри UpdateUI progressBar.PerfomStep и обновление лейблов.
И всё работает нормально.

Но тут решил переписать приложение через паттерн MVP на WinForms.
ParseNumbersAsync я перенёс в презентер, а DoWork лежит в модели.

Но непонятно, как в таком случае из DoWork обновлять UI?
Пробовал через контекст и Post, пробовал через Invoke и через Task.Factory.StartNew, но приложение начинает работать словно оно синхронное, форму даже подвигать нельзя. Стоит закаментить метод для обновления UI и снова появляется асинхронность.

Простые приложения с UI у меня получается делать с асинхронными операциями, а когда надо добраться до UI через пару слоёв, то пока не понял как сделать.

Comment: В многослойной архитектуре через пару слоёв делать не очень хорошо, но когда надо -- для этого пользуются паттерном "наблюдатель" (observer).

Comment: А если по каким-то причинам необходимо таки пробраться через пару слоёв, то каким образом надо такое реализовывать, что бы асинхронность не нарушалась?